# CSS - admin bar :hover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to style a button on the admin bar. It worked out quite well, but it has some flaws.

This button is located on the admin bar and has the text "maintenance". Once the button is clicked, jQuery will add the class `.flicker` to it.

[image]

What I want the button to do is this; once `.flicker` is applied, there should be no hover effect. However, if the `.flicker` class isn't applied, the hover effect should be default (the blue text and grayish background).

This is the HTML:

```
<ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wpmaintenance" class="wpmaintenance-icon"><a class="ab-item" href="#"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">Maintenance</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

using the following default WordPress CSS:

```
#wpadminbar .ab-top-menu>li.hover>.ab-item, #wpadminbar.nojq .quicklinks .ab-top-menu>li>.ab-item:focus, #wpadminbar:not(.mobile) .ab-top-menu>li:hover>.ab-item, #wpadminbar:not(.mobile) .ab-top-menu>li>.ab-item:focus {
    background: #32373c;
    color: #00b9eb;
}
```

with my own CSS:

```
.flicker, .flicker:hover {
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: try to add the `!important` tag in your css file.

Comment: @C0dekid Sorry, the question was a bit confusing, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the hover event to the .flickler class style and set it as default style, using !important will override other hover statement

```
.flicker:hover{
    background: #32373c !important;
    color: #00b9eb !important;
}
```

Comment: can you create a snippet of the code in order to let us understand better?

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you are looking for?

```css
.link:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.link.flicker {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.flicker:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Maitnenance</a>
<a href="#" class="link flicker">Maitnenance</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that although you are adding CSS to the .flicker:hover state, you are only adding styles, you are not removing/overriding the existing ones.

```
.flicker, .flicker:hover {
    background: white; #what color you want
    color: black; #what color you want
    -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 2s infinite;
}
```

This means that when the flicker class is added it will override the hover state changes added by the default wordpress css (provided your CSS come after).

If you are worried about your css not being applied after the default styles you can always add !important to give it more specificity.

```
e.g: background: white!important;
```

Hope it helps